# How to separate strings into 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector

This is the file with data that I'm reading from:

```
MATH201,Discrete Mathematics
CSCI300,Introduction to Algorithms,CSCI200,MATH201
CSCI350,Operating Systems,CSCI300
CSCI101,Introduction to Programming in C++,CSCI100
CSCI100,Introduction to Computer Science
CSCI301,Advanced Programming in C++,CSCI101
CSCI400,Large Software Development,CSCI301,CSCI350
CSCI200,Data Structures,CSCI101
```

I have successfully read from the file and stored this information in a 2D Vector, but when I check the size of specific rows using `course.info[x].size()` it appears that its only counting the strings that have spaces between them. So for example, `course.info[2].size()` returns 2, whereas I would rather it would return 3. Essentially I want it to count each bit of information that is separated by a comma instead of a space.  If I use `while (getline(courses, line, ',')` it puts the information separated by a comma in their own row, which is not what I want.

```
void LoadFile() {
vector<vector<string>> courseInfo;


ifstream courses;
courses.open("CourseInfo.txt");

if (!courses.is_open()) {
    cout << "Error opening file";
}

if (courses) {
    string line;

    while (getline(courses, line)) {
        courseInfo.push_back(vector<string>());

        stringstream split(line);
        string value;

        while (split >> value) {
            courseInfo.back().push_back(value);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < courseInfo.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < courseInfo[i].size(); j++)
        std::cout << courseInfo[i][j] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getline(.., .., ',')` is the tool for the job, but you need to use it in a different place.

Replace `while (split >> value)` with `while (getline(split, value, ',')`.